# Who was the spirit that rested on Eldad and Medad

Tags: tanach, commentaries

Who was the spirit that rested on Eldad and Medad?

Two men remained in the camp, one named Eldad, and the other named Medad, and the spirit rested on them; they were among those registered, but they had not gone out to the tent, and so they prophesied in the camp. Numbers 11:26-11:26

Comment: See the previous verse!!!!! The _spirit_ rested on the 70 chosen and they prophecised - and then the _spirit_ rested on Eldad and Medad. You guessed it! The spirit of prophecy. What is your question?

Comment: The spirit is generally not a person.

Comment: @DanF Where can one read when the spirit is a person? (I understand that "The Spirit is generally not a person" which indicates at times or once or twice that it is?)

Answer (score 0):

The Malbi"m here explains that prophecy generally flows through those worthy to those less worthy. In the case of the Seventy Elders, they received their prophecy through Moses when they gathered in the Mishkan. However, Eldad and Meidad were different than the other Seventy, in that they were worthy in their own right to receive prophecy. Immediately upon being registered, the prophetic spirit rested on them and because of that they had no need - and didn't go - to the Mishkan with the rest of the Elders.

> ולדעתי, האנשים האלה היו מוכנים לנבואה מצד עצמם, וכל הנביאים בדור ההוא קבלו נבואתם מכחו של משה שהוא היה הצנור המריק שפע הנבואה לכלם, כי דרך האור האלהי להתפלש דרך המאורות הגדולים על הקטנים ובל שימצא מאור יותר גדול יתפלש האור עליו עד שהוא יעשה צנור ואמצעי להריק האור על ידו על הכוכבים הקטנים כמו שתקבל הארץ אור השמש בלילה באמצעות הירח, והיה אז פני משה כפני חמה ופני יהושע כפני לבנה ופני מצדיקי הרבים הזקנים ככוכבים, שהאצילו אור פני משה על העם. אמנם אלדד ומידד היו מאורות גדולים בפני עצמם עד שהיו מוכנים לקבל האור האלהי ושפע הנבואה שלא באמצעות משה בצנור בפני עצמו, ותיכף שנכתבו בין הכתובים הנבחרים מכל שבט חל עליהם הרוח, וע"כ לא יצאו האהלה שתחול עליהם הרוח באמצעות משה כי, חל עליהם הרוח בפ"ע, ונשארו במחנה, בשגם כי אחר שהיתה מעלתם גדולה כ"כ לא היה אפשר עוד שיהיו ממנין הזקנים שהיה צריך שיהיו זקני העם ר"ל המוכנים להנהגה שפלה טבעיית (כנ"ל  פסוק ט"ז) והם היתה מעלתם גבוהה מזה

Accordingly "the spirit" in posuk 26 refers to prophetic spirit in general. While in 25 "the spirit" is "the spirit that was on Moses (26:17)" that was shared by the 70 Elders.